# How to return member that can be changed?

Tags: c++

Multi thread enviroment . The content of Foo can be multi thread.

```
class Foo
{
public:
   const A & getA() {return a_;} //has guard
   void setA(A newA){a_ = newA;} //has guard

private:
    A a_;
};
```

caller:

```
A a  = foo.getA();
```

in another question that i asked someone told me that 
[If you return const& it's guaranteed that life time of variable will be prolonged to lifetime of the reference](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)
, so according to this i dont need to copy the value and i safe even if call to setA on foo done right after i call to getA, but a lot of argument against it was araised , so i feel that this is not correct.

I want to be on the safe side so i change the signature to be :

```
A & getA() {return a_;}
```

but the compiler still give me warning that i have reference to local variable. i dont understand why, because as far as i understand (new to cpp) the return value is a copy of foo.a, so what the problem with this?

i am not worried about change of a_ content.(_a.age =4) . i worry about call to set and that my 'a' in the caller will be illegal

Comment: You are returning a reference, but copying it into `a`. If you want a reference to the variable, save it in `const A &`. If you want to change it later, drop the `const` both here and in `getA`.

Comment: What compiler and options are you using? I get no warnings for any of your code with gcc -Wall --pedantic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be more careful who you listen to. The only time the lifetime of something gets extended if a *temporary object* is bound immediately to a const-reference. For example, like so:

```
Foo bar() { return Foo(); }

int main()
{
    Foo const & f = bar();

    /* stuff */

} // the object referred to by f is extended till here
```

Your situation is nothing like that. In particular, *returning a const-reference* does not create a temporary object, so there's nothing here who's life gets prolonged. In particular, the following is *definitely* an error:

```
A const & bar() { Foo x; return x.getA(); }

int main()
{
    A const & a = bar(); // dangling reference; object dies upon return from Foo::getA()
}
```

Comment: To be sure. 
Thread 1  - A const & a = foo.getA(); 
Thread 2  - setA(..);   
Does a in thread 1 is still legal?

Comment: @user1495181, yes. The reference is still referencing the same `a_` object. (you need the guards though)

Comment: Sorry , for nagging. the original a_ was replaced (after call to getA execute call to setA) by the set , but since i have in the caller ' A const & a  ' than the original a_ is still exist somewhere on the stack despite that now a_ has another value. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @Kerrek: It's not that he listened to the wrong person, it's that he _misunderstood Herb Sutter_.

Comment: @user1495181: No copies are made, ever. All the references are to the *same* object, and if you make changes to it concurrently, it is *your* responsibility to synchronize those properly.