# Why when using in const& in the assignment disructor called , but assignment is correct

Tags: c++, callstack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to return member that can be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744265/how-to-return-member-that-can-be-changed)

I learn that if i use in const& in the assignment (and in the called method signature) than the lifetime of the refereed object is extended until end of method.

```
Employee const& getEmp(int a) {
    return Employee(a);
}
Employee const& tmpEmp = m.getEmp(10);  //
... stuff 
//end of scope - tmpEmp valid until here
```

I wrote little program and saw that it work as expected.
My question is not how to do this?
My question is about how compiler do this?
As you see from the example the  destructor is called immediately after return , so i wonder how is that the destructor called , but tmpEmp is valid after the desructor called ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
public:
    Employee() : a(0){
        cout << "c-emp" << a << endl;
    }
    Employee(const Employee& newE) {
        a = newE.a;
        cout << "c-c-emp" << a << endl;
    }
    Employee(int a) : a(a) {
        cout << "c-emp" << a << endl;
    }
    ~Employee() {
        cout << "d-emp" << a << endl;
    }
    int a;
};
class Manager {
public:
    Manager() {}
    ~Manager() {}
    Employee const& getEmp(int a) {
        return Employee(a);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Manager m;
    Employee const& tmpEmp = m.getEmp(10);
    cout << "tmpEmp " << tmpEmp.a <<endl;
}

output:
c-emp10
d-emp10   - destructor is called and tmpEmp is still valid? how is that?
tmpEmp 10
```

Comment: You learned it wrong. Only the lifetime of *temporary objects* is extended, and only if those are *immediately* bound to a const-reference; and they're only extended to the lifetime of *that* reference variable.

Comment: Also, you asked [the exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744265/how-to-return-member-that-can-be-changed) already yesterday.

Comment: @KerrekSB,@jrok,@Prætorian,@ecatmur,@R. Martinho Fernandes , my question here is not how to do this.  i know that it work. my question is how it work? where this temporary object exist? how destructor called but it still exist?

Comment: But, it *doesn't* work, that's the point.  What you are doing is undefined behavior, so whatever you see in your output is irrelevant.

Comment: Broken code can look like it "works", but it's still not valid. What you're doing is like examining a corpse and determining that it must be alive since the contents of its wallet is the same as before it died.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You learned wrong.

First, assignment *never* has any effect on the lifetime of an object.
It's just an operator with a side effect.

Second, if you initialize (not assign) a const reference with a
temporary, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the
lifetime of the reference.  There are exceptions, however.  (And I've
never found any pratical use for this feature.)

A const reference used as a return value is one of the exceptions (for
the simple reason that it's not implementable).  Initializing a return
of a const reference type with a temporary does *not* extend the life of
the temporary.

And finally, even if it did, it wouldn't help you in your case, because
the reference which was initialized by the temporary ceases to exist
after the full expression which invokes the function.

Comment: Let me see if i understand you correct. the temporary is the return value. when i return employee (without const&), a new temporary instance of employee is created for the result. if i dont use in const& in the assignment that this temporary object is copied to the assignment. if i use with const& in the assignment than the assignment will use the temporary instance? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: The temporary is the expression to the right of the `return`.  If the return type is simply `Employee&`, returning a temporary is illegal (although VC++ won't complain).  As for "the assignment": there's no assignment in any of the code you posted.  And when dealing with references, no objects get copied.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong. You are returning a reference to a local object, and the local object is not eligible for the lifetime extension you learned about. The lifetime of local objects end before you even get a chance to assign the return value to another variable, and therefore there's no way to extend their lifetime.

The lifetime extension is for temporary objects:

```
Employee getEmp(int a) {
    return Employee(a);
}
Employee const& tmpEmp = m.getEmp(10);  //
... stuff 
//end of scope - tmpEmp valid until here
```

Now getEmp() returns a temporary object (not a reference to a local object,) and that object is still valid when the assignment occurs. So its lifetime gets extended.