# How to minimize the times that list constructor (either copy-constructor ) is called?

Tags: c++

I have the following compare method.
The method compare and return diff result.

I want to minimize the times that the result list is copied (to temporal and to assignment).

One way to do this is to add additional reference argument for the result, but i love that utils function are closed (they dont change values), so i prefer to avoid this.

One copy can be avoid by using the const& in the assignment

```
const& list<uint32> diff = getDiffNewElements (...)
```

, can be a way to also avoid the local copy to temporal ?

The diff method:

```
list<uint32> getDiffNewElements(const list<Row>& src ,const list<Row>& dst) {
    list<uint32> result;

        ... Do Some compare

        return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that copy is there? Any decent compiler should be able to skip that copy.

Comment: Actually, using `const&` in the assignment doesn't avoid any copies. Also, your code is already optimal, either all the copies will be elided, or the `list` will be moved (not copied) out of the function and in to `diff`.

Comment: Your diff method looks fine, since you are likely to get a type of copy ellision called .[return value optimiztion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: change  yoru function to getDiffNewElements(const list<Row>& src ,const list<Row>& dst, list<uint32>& result) ?

Comment: @billz i dont want to pass result argument (see in my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are potentially two copies in the code that you present. One inside the function, from the variable `result` to the returned object. NRVO will take care of that if the complexity of the function allows for it. If as it seems, you have a single return statement, then the compiler will elide that copy (assuming that you are not disabling it with compiler flags and that you have *some* optimization level enabled).

The second potential copy is in the caller, from the returned value to the final storage. That copy is almost always elided by the compiler, and it is even simpler to do here than in the NRVO case: the calling convention (all calling conventions I know of) determines that the caller reserves the space for the returned object, and that it passes a hidden pointer to that location to the function. The function in turn uses that pointer as the destination of the first copy.

A function `T f()` is transformed into `void f( uninitialized<T>* __ret )` (there is no such thing as `uninitialized<>`, but bear with me) and the implementation of the function uses that pointer as the destination when copying in the `return` statement. On the caller site, if you have `T a = f();` the compiler will transform it into `T a/*no construction here*/; f(&a);`

There is an interesting bit of code in the question that seems to indicate that you have been mislead in the past: `const list<uint32>& diff = getDiffNewElements(...)`. Using a reference rather than storing the value directly (as in `list<uint32> diff = getDiffNewElements(...)`) has no impact at all in the number of copies that are made. The `getDiffNewElements` still needs to *copy* (or elide the copy) to the returned object and that object lives in the scope of the caller. By taking a const reference you are telling the compiler that you don't want to directly name that object, but rather keep it as an unnamed object in the scope and that you only want to use a reference to it. Semantically it can be transformed into:

```
T __unnamed = getDiffNewElements(...);  // this copy can be elided
T const& diff = __unnamed;
```

The compiler is free, and will probably, optimize the reference away, using the identifier `diff` as an alias to `__unnamed` without requiring extra space, so in general it will not be worse than the alternative, but the code is slightly more complex and there is no advantage at all.

Long time ago, when I had time, I started a blog and wrote a couple of articles on value semantics, (N)RVO and copy elision. You might want to take a look.

- [NRVO](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html)
- [Copy elision](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html)

Comment: can you please look on Kerrek answer there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744265/how-to-return-member-that-can-be-changed he said that "The only time the lifetime of something gets extended if a temporary object is bound immediately to a const-reference." this is the reason i use const&

Comment: @user1495181: There are very few good use cases for extending the lifetime of a temporary, and this is not one of them. Semantically the caller wants a *copy* of the result. Using the life extension feature in the language means that you want to *ignore* what the function returned and only handle an *alias* that is `const` and might be of a different type. That is where life extension adds value: you can grab a reference to a base of the returned object ignoring what the exact type is. You can read this: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: According to his answer there i thought its a must (for prevent the copy.) . Thanks a lot for clarify

Comment: @user1495181: That copy will be *elided*, using the `const&` will only make the code more convoluted :) -- An interesting read on the single valid use case for the lifetime extension: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758. Regarding the answer you linked, what Kerrek is trying to make clear is that returning a `const&` won't extend the lifetime of the object inside the function. Don't take it as a recommendation to always use `const&` on the call side.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong direction. Your `getDiffNewElements` method does not create unnecessary copies, because modern compilers do [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (which was pointed in the comments, although if your compiler doesn't do RVO, there is nothing you can do about it, your `const&` won't help). The way you can optimize this function is to return `vector` instead of `list`, since you can call `reserve` on `vector` and avoid memory allocations every time you `push_back` a new element. `list` does not preallocate memory with default allocator and it has no `reserve` method to do that.

Comment: The `const&` is not intended to help with the copy that NRVO elides (from `result` to the temporary object that is the return value of `getDiffNewElements`), it's intended to help with the *other* copy (from the temporary that is the return value of `getDiffNewElements`, to `diff`). But what you say is probably still true: in practice a compiler that can do NRVO can elide the other copy as well. But that's because it has copy elision enabled rather than specifically because it can do NRVO.

Comment: @SteveJessop let me see if i understood correct. we have 2 copies here one from local to temporal and one from temporal to assignment.The first one will be saved due to 'copy elision' the second one will be saved due to NRVO and only if i use const&

Comment: @user1495181: no. If you had written `list<uint32_t> diff = getDiffNewElements(...)` then there would be two copies, one inside the function (from `result` to a temporary), and one outside the function (from the temporary to `diff`). The first one could be saved by NRVO (which is a kind of copy elision), and the second could also be saved by copy elision. Since you wrote `const&`, though, there is no second copy in your code, regardless of whether the compiler does copy elision. In fact, all optimizing C++ compilers do copy elision, including NRVO. You can turn it off in `gcc`.